# How add a square bracket to end of line in file using VIM

Tags: vim

I have a text file with more than 500000 lines. I am using VIM to edit these files.

My text has set of square brackets in each line. Unfortunately, some of the lines don't have closing square brackets.

```
some text [ text

some text [ text]

some text [ text]

some text [ text

some text [ text]
```

I need my text to be

```
some text [text]

some text [text]

some text [text]

some text [text]

some text [text]
```

I'd like to know how to accomplish the result above using Vim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PeterRincker's solutions seem great to add a `]` at the end of selected lines.

Here is a proposal to add a `]` in one command to all non-empty lines of file not ending with `]` (or with `]`, followed by spaces):

```
:%s/[^\]]\+ *$/&]/
```

Comment: Hi Peter,Thanks for replying to me. Can you assist me how to execute this command in background or is there any other way to execute this command using bash ,awk or in sed. because my files contains 700000 lines. if i execute this  command directly in vim editor of my server means my server hangs up

Comment: Hi @user1865445, I'm not Peter but here is a `sed` line anyway: `sed 's/[^]]\+ *$/&]/' your_file.txt`. The only difference is that I suppressed first `\ ` in the expression.

Answer (score 4):

```
:%s/[^\]]$/&]
```

substitutes every last character before EOL that is not a `]` with itself followed by a `]`, essentially adding a trailing bracket where there is none.

Now, in your initial snippet the opening bracket is separated by a space from the word that follows so you may need to run a second substitution to clean the whole thing up:

```
:%s/\[\s*/[
```

Answer (score 2):

So many ways:

- visual block - `<c-v>` then select all the lines then press `$A]<esc>`
- substitue - `:%s/$/]/`
- via normal ex-command - `:%normal A]`
- macros - `qqA]jq` then execute via `500000@q`

Personally I would go with a the substitution.

Comment: Yeah, substitution is fastest to type, fastest to run and most precise.